# Generate a BigInteger from the specified intValue

Tags: java, c#, biginteger

`BigInteger.intValue()` is a one way operation which can loose some information of the `BigInteger`. So it is not possible to get the exact original `BigInteger`.
I want to know how could I generate a `BigInteger` for the same resulted `intValue` in Java?
And since it is somehow independently related to the bitwise operations, how it is possible in other languages like C#?

Comment: use one of the BigInteger constructors

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. The `BigInteger.intValue()` method simply returns the low-order 32 bits of the BigInteger as an `int`. Therefore, if `x` is your BigInteger, and `k` is *any* other BigInteger, then `x.intValue() == x.add(k.shiftLeft(32)).intValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

For a value greater than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`and less than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger( value );
i.equals( BigInteger.valueOf( i.intValue() );
```

would be `true`. It does not really matter here that `BigInteger.valueOf()` takes a `long` argument.

For values outside the mentioned range, `BigInteger.intValue()` will not return the correct value, so you cannot reconstruct the original `BigInteger` from that result, by no means.

So there is no safe way from `BigInteger` to `int` working for all possible values. This implies that there also no way back …

---

BigInteger is a class in Java. This means that there is no mean to get a BigInteger just from mere bit manipulation (aside from some very, very, VERY dirty hacks with some JNI code or by another ugly mean to manipulate the memory directly in the JVM). So the only way to get a new `BigInteger` instance is to call the respective constructor.

Something like the C# code below

```
BigInteger temp = myInt + n * (BigInteger)(uint.MaxValue) * (BigInteger) Math.Pow( 2, 32 );
```

will not work in Java, not with `BigInteger`. It starts with that (something like) auto-boxing is not implemented for `BigInteger`, so that already this will cause the compiler to go on strike:

```
BigInteger temp = 1;
```

The `+` operator is also not defined for `BigInteger` in Java, so this will just not compile, too:

```
BigInteger a1 = …
BigInteger a2 = …
BigInteger result = a1 + a2;
```

Even when we would assume that `a1` and `a2` had been properly initialised.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking for bitwise concept not java specific methods, in order to extend the solution to other languages. And I know that there is no way back, but looking for the best way to reproduce a BigInteger with the same  intValue. e.g. this simple code in C#: BigInteger temp = myInt + n*(BigInteger)(uint.MaxValue)*(BigInteger)Math.Pow(2,32);

Comment: @getpaidsz – But you are aware that `BigInteger` is a class in Java? This means that there is no mean to get a `BigInteger` just from mere bit manipulation (aside from some very, very, VERY dirty hacks with some JNI code or by another mean to manipulate the memory directly in Java). So the only way to get a new `BigInteger` instance is to call the respective constructor.